Override method for family using annotations
Using riverpod_annotation how do you override the value of the provider? It looks like it's missing an override method.
@riverpod
class Foo extends _$Foo {
  @override
  int build(int val) => val;
}

runApp(ProviderScope(
  overrides: [
    // Doesn't exist
    fooProvider.overrideWith(),    // or something similar
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
));


It's not related to riverpod_annotation, it's just the fact that you use the class-based syntax, which creates a notifier provider. See: Mocking Notifiers
